# Incomplete inner product space has a subspace such that the direct sum with orthogonal isn't the whole space

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products

I would like to show that for any incomplete inner product space $H$ there exists a closed subspace $H_0$ such that

$H_0 + H_0^{\bot}\neq H$

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3863717/inner-product-space-not-the-direct-sum-of-subspace-and-orthogonal-complement) and [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3737702/closed-linear-subspace-of-incomplete-inner-product-space) vere slightly relevant discussion.

I saw an example for continuous functions (complex inner product inherited from $L_2$) and a subspace of functions such that $\int_0^1 f(t) dt = \int_{-1}^{0} f(t) dt$  which is closed and is not the whole subspace, but the orthogonal complement is zero.

We could may be prove that there always exists a subspace such that the orthogonal complement to $H_0$ in the completion of the space $H$ doesn't lie in the image of $H$ under the standard isometric injection into the completion.